# Scraping Iframe Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a live score from a dynamic website (https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/cricket/international-odi-matches/group_c.37afeb89-7976-47fd-9f17-29c5777e43cd/2nd-odi-bangladesh-v-sri-lanka).

I know I need to fetch the URL in the `iframe src` and I thought the code below would do the job but I can't get it to work. The version below gives an error.

> "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error.

What am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/cricket/international-odi-matches/group_c.37afeb89-7976-47fd-9f17-29c5777e43cd/2nd-odi-bangladesh-v-sri-lanka")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = soup.find("iframe").attrs["src"]

r = s.get(f"https:{iframe_src}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for container in soup.find("sb-ms-score"):
    score = container.find("span", {"data-gp-sb-callback": "updateMainScore"}).text.strip()
    print(score)
```

Edit:

So it seems the iframe content is in javascript so I've tried to build in Selenium. The updated code is here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_driver_path = 'geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_driver_path)
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/tennis/utr-pro-match-series-womens/group_b.87d1e4ea-be95-4bc4-99d4-47f105484ecd/r-kolzer-v-b-passola")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

score_section = soup.find('section', class_='scoreboard gp')

iframe_src = score_section.find("iframe").attrs["src"]

r2 = driver.get(iframe_src)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, "html.parser")

pp = soup2.find('div', class_='sb-ms-inplay')

print(pp)
```

This throws up the error below at this line: `soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, "html.parser")`. This seems strange to me because when I print iframe_src it returns the iframe url correctly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/SportingIndex v9.py", line 18, in <module>
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, "html.parser")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Note the URL is different as yesterday's game is no longer live.

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: `soup.find("sb-ms-score")` is `None`... hence your error.

Comment: And there are two `<iframe />` on the page... perhaps you're not getting the _right one_?

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a couple of problems with your approach, but the main one is your use of `soup.find()`.

This code should illustrate:

```py
>>> r = s.get("https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/cricket/international-odi-matches/group_c.37afeb89-7976-47fd-9f17-29c5777e43cd/2nd-odi-bangladesh-v-sri-lanka")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
>>> soup.find("iframe")
<iframe height="0" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-K9B9HG" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0"></iframe>
>>> soup.find_all("iframe")
[<iframe height="0" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-K9B9HG" style="display:none;visibility:hidden" width="0"></iframe>, <iframe height="200" scrolling="no" src="https://scoreboards.sportingsolutions.com/cricket.html#event_id=928c138f-bfa3-4bc3-acd8-b640ad7603d2&amp;&amp;customer=sportingindex&amp;feed=extended" style="overflow: hidden; border: 0px" width="600"></iframe>]
```

i.e. `find()` returns *one* result, whereas `find_all()` returns *all*.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below gets you a step further, but the content you are looking for `"sb-ms-score"` is not in the urls you are looking up

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
 
s = requests.Session() 
r = s.get("https://www.sportingindex.com/spread-betting/cricket/international-odi-matches/group_c.37afeb89-7976-47fd-9f17-29c5777e43cd/2nd-odi-bangladesh-v-sri-lanka") 
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") 
iframe_src = soup.find_all("iframe") 
 
for ifr in iframe_src: 
    _src_str = "{:}".format(ifr["src"]) 
    if "https" not in _src_str: 
        _url = "https:{:}".format(iframe_src[0]["src"]) 
    else: 
        _url = _src_str 
    r = s.get(_url) 
    print(_url) 
    print(r) 
    _soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") 
    for container in _soup.find_all("sb-ms-score"): 
        print(container)
```

Comment: Thanks guys. What do you mean the content is not in the urls Braulio?

Comment: hey @Andy, look up the contents of `_soup` it seemed to me that they did not contain `sb-ms-score` although the url request `s.get(_url)` was successful, I hope that helps you!

Comment: @Andy btw for the question you asked either of the answers should have clarified your type error, or?